# Force third party code to use another ILogger implementation

Tags: .net, .net-core, logging, dependency-injection

Most Microsoft and third party owned libraries distributed through Nuget use the debug windows as a default logging target (among others). App Center and EF Core packages are just two instances.

I am using a `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILogger` implementation with customized formatting and output targets, and would like to capture the logs of those libraries within my custom log.

My assumption was that populating its implementation through the `ServiceProvider` would  replace the default Logger and have third party code depending on the `ILogger` use it instead. But they are still merely logging to the console in regular format.

I can think of a few possible reasons why this is the case:

- These unmanaged Class libraries are oblivious to the ServiceProvider.
- The packages actually do not depend on the `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILogger` interface for logging.
- They do, but they prefer their implementation over any the registered. It would require a public method to force the class library to use another Logger (most packages do not provide such an interface).
- I am missing some other services that I need to provide an implementation for (such as ILoggerFactory for instance).

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

For [EF Core](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/), you can integrate with your logging infrastructure [by defining a logger factory injection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/logging-events-diagnostics/extensions-logging?tabs=v3) for the DbContext:

(from the docs)

```
public static readonly ILoggerFactory MyLoggerFactory
    = LoggerFactory.Create(builder => { builder.AddConsole(); });
```

> This singleton/global instance should then be registered with EF Core
> on the DbContextOptionsBuilder. For example:

```
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    => optionsBuilder
        .UseLoggerFactory(MyLoggerFactory)
        .UseSqlServer(@"Server=(localdb)\mssqllocaldb;Database=EFLogging;Trusted_Connection=True");
```

Comment: EF Core is the only one I got working so far as I am using it in ASP.NET Core; according to the docs: "EF Core fully integrates with Microsoft.Extensions.Logging and this form of logging is used by default for ASP.NET Core applications." This is essentially the behaviour I would expect from every class library even for regular console applications.